# KML: How to draw a border/outline for a Icon in GroundOverlay

Tags: qgis, kml

I want to add a red color border/outline to . How can I achieve it. Working with QGIS

```
<kml>
    <Document>
        <name>GeoTIFF Overlays</name>
        <GroundOverlay>
            <Icon>
                <href>1.tif</href>
            </Icon>
            <LatLonBox>
                <north>3946515.0</north>
                <south>3712185.0</south>
                <east>636315.0</east>
                <west>406185.0</west>
            </LatLonBox>
        </GroundOverlay>
    </Document>
</kml>
```